# How to convert month in MMM('Apr') to M(4) in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have just got a length three string for month field which can have values like 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar' etc. I would like to know if there's a way to get their corresponding month number using Moment.js?

I tried `moment('Apr').format('M')` but got an `Invalid Date` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the format of the string to the constructor as well:

```js
console.log(moment('Apr', 'MMM').format('M'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js
"></script>
```